# Python function doesnt work properly when imported, only when locally defined

Tags: python, function, variables, import, global

I have a file called `functions.py` in my project directory which contains a few simple functions.

One of these functions (`load()`) is supposed to create global variables without requiring the user to define them beforehand.

When I import the functions from the file using

```
from functions import load
```

It doesn't work properly, meaning the global variables are not created.

However, when I copy paste the function to define it instead of importing from the file, it works properly. Here is the complete function:

```
def load(cnv):

    global hd1, hd2, variables, datapoints
    hd1, hd2, variables, datapoints  = [], [], [], []

    o = open(cnv)
    r = o.readlines()
    o.close()

    for line in r:
        if not line:
            pass
        elif line.startswith('*'):
            hd1.append(line)
        elif line.startswith('#'):
            hd2.append(line)
            if line.startswith('# name'):
                line = line.split()
                variables.append(line[4])
        else:
            float_list = []
            line = line.split()
            for item in line:
                float_list.append(float(item))
            datapoints.append(float_list)

    datapoints = filter(None, datapoints)

    global df
    df = pd.DataFrame(datapoints, columns = variables)
```

By the way there is an indent in the whole body of the function after the def() statement. I'm not sure why it doesn't appear when I paste it in this post.

I am very new to programming so I'm taking suggestions on how to potentially improve this code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for the input.

However, when I try:

def foo():
    global a
    a = 25

if I run:
f()

and type
print(a)

The output is 25, even if I haven't defined a beforehand. Meaning it created a 'global' a from inside the function.

Comment: @ViniSalazar may you also paste how you are trying to use the global variables. You should try functions.hd1 for accessing

Comment: @ViniSalazar Disregard my previous comment. I hadn't used `global` in a while, and was rusty on the details.

Answer (score 1):

The "global" variables are not really global to the scope of the whole script. This is not PHP.

Python has everything structure to the per-module namespaces. The variables are "global" to the scope of the module, where that function is declared. So, when you import the function and call it, it creates the variables which can be accessed as `functions.hd1`, `functions.hd2`, etc.

Comment: thanks a lot. this answers why it wasn't working when importing from the functions file. however, do you know a way I could modify it so I can access it only by typing "hd1", "hd2", etc?

I'm trying to make things easier for the end user, what I was doing before was making local variables but the user would have to call the function like this:

hd1, hd2, variables, datapoints, df = load('myfile')

Comment: sorry I just tried this and it returned:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-6ad634921efe> in <module>()
----> 1 functions.hd1
 
NameError: name 'functions' is not defined

Comment: No. This is against the Python idea of modules & per-module namespaces. You cannot have a custom name in all modules without importing it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you use it. For using global you need to first call load function to initialize the variables after which u can use it using the package.variable.

Please find the below implementation.

```
#functions.py
def load():
    global hd1
    hd1 = []

#test.py
import functions
functions.load()
functions.hd1.append('hey')
print functions.hd1
```

OR

```
#test.py
from functions import load
load()
from functions import *
hd1.append('hey')
print hd1
```

Comment: thanks. do you if there is a way I can call the variable without having to type 'functions.' before? just by typing the variable name?

Comment: Check the updated answer. But need to remember the statements while writing program and easy to break it. So its better to use recommended way with file name.